# Miner vs Builder Rewards?

Tags: mev-boost

I'm trying to understand the relative payments to miners and builders in MEV-Boost. I have a block like this one (https://beaconcha.in/slot/5603982). What I interpret from this block is that

1. The block builder is 0x535b918f3724001fd6fb52fcc6cbc220592990a3
2. The builder gets a fee of 0.06084 Ether from the Miner
3. The block miner is 0x95222290dd7278aa3ddd389cc1e1d165cc4bafe5
4. The miner gets a reward of 0.05911 Ether for mining the block

What I'm confused about is that it seems the net miner reward is negative since 0.05911<0.06804. Is the miner getting a negative payoff after sending the fee to the block builder?

One thing that's missing from this calculation is the transaction fees paid to the miner. I saw there's some gas used, but I thought this does not get paid straight to the miner.